# Unhealthy backend health of server, under application gateway -> backend health status for the server is showing as unhealthy

Tags: azure, networking, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

under the status it shows , unhealthy. I have configured the https setting and connected it with the health-probe for my server. Also configured the ports in NSG. Please let me know if anyone knows the solution for the same

Answer (score 1):

When the backend health status of the Application gateway shows Unhealthy, it also show details of the error message/cause of the issue. You need to check the error message and follow the steps for that particular error message from the below troubleshooting doc to resolve it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#backend-health-status-unhealthy